# JavaFX Application with Maven in Eclipse

Tags: maven, javafx, javafx-2, maven-3, javafx-8

I want to ask if there is any method to add JavaFX into Maven Archetype list in Eclipse or any plugin to use Maven to build JavaFX Application.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is the [**javafx-maven-plugin**](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) which is available for maven.

When developing with Java 8 you just put that plugin as some build-plugin, without further dependencies.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.8.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>your.main.class.which.extends.javafx.Application</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Calling `mvn jfx:jar` creates your javafx-application-jar inside `target/jfx/app/yourapp-jfx.jar`, or even creates native launcher (like EXE-file) when calling `mvn jfx:native`.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin.

Comment: It's a bit outdated and not fully finished, but you can use our configuration-creation website: http://javafx-maven-plugin.github.io/

Comment: It's for maven only or we can integrate it with eclipse. I mean running like application on eclipse.

Comment: That maven-plugin just wrapps the commandline-calls for javapackager. You should be able to create your own run-command to execute `java -jar target/jfx/app/yourapp-jfx.jar`. Running javafx-applications is different, because of the possabilities for JVM-arguments, so just calling the main-method is not how javafx-applications are working.

Comment: These answers are old. The correct (current) answer is available here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Answer (score 8):

The only thing I add to my `pom.xml` in order to build JavaFX Application is this dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

It is simply fetching the javafx jar in my Java8 JRE to add it to the project.
Then I use the `maven-assembly-plugin` to build the jar with dependencies.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is copied from the documentation at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven. More detailed information (including a full sample pom.xml reference) is available at the link provided.

The pom uses the JavaFX Maven plugin:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Add the maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>13</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Run the application (e.g. based on the HelloFX.java from the referred sample):

`mvn clean javafx:run`

**Note regarding other outdated answers**

1. Previous (highly-voted) answers which reference the `com.zenjava` `javafx-maven-plugin` are outdated, as that plugin is not coded to work with recent JavaFX versions.  For Java versions 10+, the `org.openjfx` `javafx-maven-plugin` should be used.
2. Also, for Java 10+, answers which reference *only* the assembly plugin and state that JavaFX is included in the JDK, are also outdated. JavaFX is no longer bundled in recent JDK releases, instead it is available as a separate SDK from openjfx.io or as a set of library dependencies from the maven central repository.

Answer (score 1):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do as a common Java application because JavaFX version jumped to 8.0. Supports for JavaFX are built-in.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run application</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>cn.keepfight.intro.FXParamApp</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <!--<argument>-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true</argument>-->
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```