# Eclipse compiling java but with errors in the log

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse and i keep getting this error. I have deleted .metadata folder multiple times to get it working. Is there something I am missing?
I have cleaned the project but with no luck
I can see class files being updated but after iis reset nothing changes on my web page.

```
!SESSION 2017-08-28 14:41:50.407 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide 2 17 2017-08-28 14:42:10.254
!MESSAGE Server ‘org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server’ failed with exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. ; version: 2.0.5.v20170613-1207
!STACK 0
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.internalExecute(Request.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor.execute(Executor.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.request(IO.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.refreshConfiguration(IO.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.ServerConnection.startUp(ServerConnection.java:124)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2017-08-28 14:42:12.043
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\kdoshi'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Comment: Do you have the certificate for the server?

Comment: I dont think so. I am new to this.. Can you please help me with the steps?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ

You will need to get a cert file into your local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps

1. install JDK and set JAVA_HOME environment variable
2. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715134/1802348) answer to know how to get and install certificate into cacerts
3. You need to Get Root CA certificate of your network.
4. You need to install that certificate into cacerts file
5. Restart eclipse