# Getting certification error in Web Service call

Tags: java, certificate, axis

I have a web service client which has been used several months, but last days we are getting an error when we execute the invocation to the method.

The error we get is :

```
[22 mar 2018 09:17:38,828] ERROR com.nisa.sms.EnviarSMS  - (EnviarSMS.java:51) - Error al enviar el sms: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

the method is called with axis and this is the code :

```
    public void enviarMensaje(int hospital, java.lang.String telefono, java.lang.String mensaje, javax.xml.rpc.holders.StringHolder respuesta, javax.xml.rpc.holders.StringHolder error) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        if (super.cachedEndpoint == null) {
            throw new org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException();
        }
        org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
        _call.setOperation(_operations[1]);
        _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
        _call.setSOAPActionURI("");
        _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
        _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
        _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
        _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
        _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://webservices.nisa.com/", "enviarMensaje"));

        setRequestHeaders(_call);
        setAttachments(_call);
 try {        java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {new java.lang.Integer(hospital), telefono, mensaje});

        if (_resp instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException) {
            throw (java.rmi.RemoteException)_resp;
        }
        else {
            extractAttachments(_call);
            java.util.Map _output;
            _output = _call.getOutputParams();
            try {
                respuesta.value = (java.lang.String) _output.get(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "respuesta"));
            } catch (java.lang.Exception _exception) {
                respuesta.value = (java.lang.String) org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.convert(_output.get(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "respuesta")), java.lang.String.class);
            }
            try {
                error.value = (java.lang.String) _output.get(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "error"));
            } catch (java.lang.Exception _exception) {
                error.value = (java.lang.String) org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.convert(_output.get(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "error")), java.lang.String.class);
            }
        }
  } catch (org.apache.axis.AxisFault axisFaultException) {
  throw axisFaultException;
}
    }
```

this method is included in a Java application and we don't have certification problem in it. The certificate is validated and the problem comes in the line:

```
java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {new java.lang.Integer(hospital), telefono, mensaje});
```

we have the code of the web service too, the application who contains it is right certificated too.

Anyway I was reviewing the certificates and they are not timed out.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Has the certificate of the web service changed? Is the root certificate included in the trust store?

Comment: Nothing was changed apparently the days before to get the error.

Comment: Was there an update of the JRE? Anything has changed...

Comment: @amanbur add your network root ssl certificate using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715134/1802348) guide.