# Failing to fetch Google dependencies PKIX Path Building failed

Tags: android, pkix

I am getting this when I build my project. I can't seem to download any of the google dependencies.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:369)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:148)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:126)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:103)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:94)
... 177 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

All of the Google dependencies that target Maven fails. Not sure what the issue.

I have tried adding the cacert to my Java certs be still fails to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Few checks to narrow down problem

1. Checkout [this GUIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715134/1802348) for certificate installation to check for any wrong step you performed.
2. Double check jre which is giving this exception is very same to which you installed your ssl root certificate

Check by typing bellow command on command prompt and see java home path and there only you are supposed to add certificate to cacerts.

```
mvn -version
```

3. Confirm it is root SSL certificate which you installed and not expired.if you install non root cert which is expired you may face issue.