# PKIX path building failed in Centos 7

Tags: java, ssl, centos7

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Receiving following exception while triggering the SSL certified URL.
Tried to fix the error by using following command

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/bin/keytool -import –alias -genkey –keystore “/opt/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/security/cacerts” -file /apps/binlistlookup/src/main/resources/binlistnet.crt
```

The issue is still percieving in **centos 7** system.

Comment: Confirm certificate you are putting is same JDK which generates error, 
Confirm certificate format, 
Certificate is ROOT certificate to ensure reliability. For help in process refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715134/1802348) post.

Answer (score 0):

1 . `keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass -validity 360 -keysize 2048`

Some request will be shown asking your general datas. Enter all of them.

2 . `keytool -v -list -keystore keystore.jks`

3 . `keytool -exportcert -rfc -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -file selfsigned.crt`

4 . `keytool -printcert -file selfsigned.crt`

Your cerfication file is ready.